# Gd and Freetype enable but still get this error Call to undefined function imagettftext()

Tags: php, gd

[image]

here is my code

```
$r = hexdec(substr($text->color, 2, 2));
$g = hexdec(substr($text->color, 4, 2));
$b = hexdec(substr($text->color, 6, 2));
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, $r, $g, $b);
$font = resource_path().'/font/arial.ttf';
imagettftext($image, 5, 0, 0, 0, $color, $font, "text");
```

I have download that font file from some webboard and move to my resource folder and i have check the arial.ttf is exist , but still got this error

> Call to undefined function imagettftext()

Thanks.

Comment: did you create the image in the $image variable and i think "text" should be 'text' which is the words it will output

Answer (score -1):

As you can see in [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php), there is a note, that this function is only available if PHP was complied with FreeType support.

```
 --with-freetype-dir=DIR
```

Step by step instructions, how to do that could be found [at ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/731351) and the first step is to install [FreeType library](http://freetype.org/download.html).